# How does video on demand over P2P work?

Tags: network-programming, video-streaming, p2p

In simple terms how does video on demand and streaming video work over P2P? I assume videos are cut up into small pieces (a few seconds each) and these pieces are transferred in chunks. As soon as a user is finished watching a chunk, it is deleted from their computer. Wouldn't this mean if no user on the network was currently watching a certain instance (chunk/time slice?) of the video then it's permanently lost? If no, how does VoD over P2P work? If you store all the chunks then it's exactly the same as normal file sharing with P2P.

Let me know if any parts of the question are unclear and I'll try to improve it.

Answer (score 1):

**P2P Live**: each user downloads and simultaneously uploads chunks for other users who watch the same stream. More users means better quality.
[image]

source: [P2P TV - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P2PTV)

**P2P VOD**: this is more challenging to achieve since like you noticed there's less simultaneity in the way users watch the video. In this case each user is expected to contribute a reasonable amount of disk space to store chunks for other users. The strategies concerning what to store on each user's cache are subject to ongoing research.

If you search for P2P VOD you will find a lot of white papers presenting different approaches. There are too many links to list here.